# Why is this matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Given the matrix $$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -1 & -2 \\
 -1 & 0 & -2 \\
 -2 & -2 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

It has the following characteristic polynomial: $-(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+5)$, yielding eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=2$. Now the algebraic multiplicity for $\lambda_1$ is 2.

For the nullspace of $A-\lambda_1I$ I row reduce the matrix and get:

$$A-\lambda_1I=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & -1 & -2 \\
 -1 & -1 & -2 \\
 -2 & -2 & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right) \Leftrightarrow \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Therefore $\ker(A-\lambda_1I)=\langle \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \rangle$, so the geometric multiplicity is only 1, and a matrix is diagonalizable iff the algebraic multiplicity equals the geometric multiplicity. Mathematica tells me the matrix is diagonalizable, but I can only come up with two eigenvectors. Where is my mistake?

Comment: $$A-\lambda_1I=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & -1 & -2 \\
 -1 & -1 & -2 \\
 -2 & -2 & {\color{red}{-4}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. I kind of expected a stupid mistake like that. But simply didn't see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All real valued symmetric matrices are diagonalizable. They are also called self adjoint.